# jQuery: How many elements between two positions in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a beyond frustrating problem which I have no idea how to tackle.

**My question**: How do I determine how many elements exist between two positions in a viewport (a scrollable div in this occasion)?

Say I have a scrollable `<div>` that has a height of 150 px, but has a viewport at 450px with the majority of it being hidden. The div has children that are 30px high, 15 of them.

**Question 2**: How could I find out how many first children exist between n1 and n2, it seems pretty easy but it's proving not to be.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9uaC/6/) where I have partly solved the solution, it works if the top value is set to 0, but it doesn't work if it's anything else. For example, with this solution I am able to determine that there are 7 visible divs between 0 and 200px. But if I change it to determine how many are between 30px and 230px it tells me 0, when again it should be 7.

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var $this = $(this),
    topOffset = $this.offset().top;
if (topOffset >= top && topOffset <= bottom) {
    elements++;
}
```

This checks to see if the current element's (in the `each()`) top offset is greater than the `top` variable's value and increases the `elements` only then. This way, you don't need to be constantly updating the `height` variable.

And this works, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/q9uaC/11/).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This seems to work best in the situation I need it in. -- edit When the bottom value is changed to something lower than 450 this returns incorrect results.

Comment: @rickibalboa: Oops, yeah, one moment.

Answer (score 2):

Change it so that the 'height' starts equal to the top value.

Your javascript should be:

```
var container = $('div#container'),
top = 30,
bottom = 230,
height = top,
elements = 0;

container.find('div').each(function(n)
{
  if (top <= height && height < bottom)
{
    height = height + $(this).height();
    elements++;
    console.log(top, bottom, height, elements);
}
});

$('span.top').text(top);
$('span.btm').text(bottom);
$('span.num').text(elements);
```

That worked for me, Good luck!